# Sort a NSMutableArray by Object values

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Here i am sorting the NSMutableArray *newsDataArray* containing the *NewsData* Objects with int property *newsID*. This is working now . But  how can i do this in a better way . Is there any better methods ...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"newsID" ascending:NO];
NSArray *tempArray = [newsDataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
NSLog(@"sortedArray=%@" ,sortedArray);
```

when i am using the following methods with block some error is showing. I want sorted newsDataArray as my final result .... Anyone give me a clear example ...

Comment: Check the answer to this question, which gives several means to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways, here by using a [comparator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW28)

For NSArray -> new Array object:

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    return [a.newsTitle compare:b.newsTitle]
}
```

For NSMutableArray -> in place:

```
[array sortUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    return [a.newsTitle compare:b.newsTitle]
}];
```

Sorting by scalars:

```
[array sortUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    if ( a.newsID < b.newsID) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( a.newsID > b.newsID) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } 
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: want to compare 'newsID' that is an int value ... how can i ...

Comment: here where i will create my objects a and b ...

Comment: its saying error ' a and b not found' ...

Comment: the method `sortUsingComparator:` passes the objects in to the block. If your code is not working, please check the documentation for blocks and these sorting methods.