# Merge NSMutableArray element in the same array by string

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures, nsmutablearray

I would like a group element in NSMutableArray like this question:
[How to implement "group by values" in NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571646/how-to-implement-group-by-values-in-nsmutablearray)

But, my problem is inside the NSMutableArray i have no values ​​but I have an object of a class model like:

```
@interface up : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

Any ideas?

> Example:

Well, practically I have an NSMutableArray and in every cell of this array I have an object of a class model. What I have to do is create a new data structure where I merge objects based on the ID. For example:

```
{
 id = 1;
 name = "test"; 

}
{
 id = 1;
 name = "test1"; 
}
{
 id = 2;
 name = "test2";
}
{
 id = 2; 
 name = "test3"; 
}
{
 id = 3;
 name = "test4"; 
}
```

Result:

```
    {
 id = 1;
 name = "test"; 
 name = "test1"; 
}
{
 id = 2;
 name = "test2";
 name = "test3"; 

}
{
 id = 3;
 name = "test4"; 
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458867/sort-a-nsmutablearray-by-object-values) what you want?

Comment: generating your expected result is not possible; what kinda output you'd like to get eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSMutableArray<NSString *> *> *newDict =  NSMutableDictionary.new;
    for( UP *up in data) {
        if (!newDict[up.id]) {
            newDict[up.id] = NSMutableArray.new;
        }
        [newDict[up.id] addObject:up.name];
    }
```

newDict is the new data structure.

Comment: Oh my god. Work perfectly! Thank you!